# How to find the direction of an "L" shape in a image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I need to find the moving direction of a vehicle by its extracted point cloud, and I have converted the point cloud to the following image.

[image: First "L"]
[image: Second "L"]
[image: Third "L"]

As the target vehicle could be moving straight or turning and the image is sometimes clear and sometimes fuzzy, I find it's difficult to match the "L" shape using template matching.

I also try to use RANSAC to fit the linear, but it has two sides and RANSAC does not work well. What I need to do is using an oriented bounding box to represent the vehicle.

If I could have the yaw angle of the "L" shape, it's very easy to recover it to an oriented bounding box. So could anyone give me some suggestions?

PS: The function `cv::minAreaRect` could offer a basic result, but it sometimes fit the "L" shape in a wrong direction.

[image: Resut of minAreaRect]

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem using `cv::minAreaRect`?

Comment: I have tried cv::minAreaRect and it's not working well. It sometimes fit the "L" model in a wrong direction. I will upload an image and you could have a look.

Comment: I can't submit while showing the image. The editor complains "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted”, and I don't know why.

Comment: Please show the code whrere you use minAreaRect. You're doing something really wrong

Comment: I find the reason why I can't post with images -- "you need at least 10 reputations to post images" and I only have 1 right now...

Comment: I'm sure that you know minAreaRect only fit an oriented rectangle with the minimum area. So it's obvious that it could fit an "L" shape in two directions. The L could either be two sides of the rectangle or inside the rectangle, as both these two rectangles have the same area.

Comment: Yes I know. And I'm pretty sure also that you didn't apply that function to white points only, but on all non-zero points in your image. So basically you're are inlcuding background points (jpeg artifacts probably) in the rectangle computation, which results to be wrong

Comment: The raw image is a binary image. The point value can only be 0 or 255.

Comment: Do you first save the image and then load it?

Comment: No, I did not save the image. So the cv::Mat representing the image is a pure black & white image, and it's not contaminated by any noise (such as jpeg artifacts you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

Build the convex hull and qualify the sides as "pretty vertical" and "pretty horizontal". This will help you identify the corners.

---

A yet simpler method is to identify the four pixels that maximimze ±X±Y. This gives you an interesting bounding quadrilateral (often reduced to a triangle).

[image]

Comment: That seems like a great approach. Do you have some source code on this?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to see what side is closer to the center of the mass, because the this center is always closer to the 'L' shape.

See the link below:

docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html